# how to add another function but different button in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show arraylist in original order when i press the original order button and When i press the alphabetical i want to show the alphabetical order of the books i've only done the original order and I tried doing the same thing when adding the alp order but nothing happens
here's the code

```js
var myArray = ["Book1",
  "Book2",
  "Book3",
  "Book4"
];

function Org() {
  var display = myArray.toString();
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = display;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<button onclick="Org()">Original Order </button>
<button onclick="Alp()"> Alphabetical Order</button>
<button onclick="Rev()"> Reverse Order</button>
```

i want to add a different function for Alphabetical order and Reverse order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort array you can use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function. Check article.

Also, to keep original array, you can use it's elements by using `[...myArray]` approach - in this case you will create new array, based on original array without changes.

To reverse array, use [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) function.

```js
// original array with strings
const myArray = ["Book1", "Book2", "Book3", "Book4"];

// getting result container
const resultContainer = document.querySelector("#result");

// render original array
const Org = () => {
  const display = [...myArray];
  renderList(display);
}

// render sorted array
const Alp = () => {
  const display = [...myArray].sort();
  renderList(display);
}

// render reverted array
const Rev = () => {
  const display = [...myArray].sort().reverse();
  renderList(display);
}

// render function itself
const renderList = (arr) => {
  // clear prev rendered list
  resultContainer.innerHTML = null;
  
  // create temporary container
  const tmpContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();
  
  arr.map(item => {
    // create temporary list element
    const tmpLi = document.createElement('li');
    // add text content to li element
    tmpLi.innerText = item;
    // add list item to temporary container
    tmpContainer.append(tmpLi);
  });
  
  // add content (list items) from temporary container to render container
  resultContainer.append(tmpContainer);
}

// call render of origin list
Org();
```

```html
<ul id="result"></ul>
<button onclick="Org()">Original Order </button>
<button onclick="Alp()"> Alphabetical Order</button>
<button onclick="Rev()"> Reverse Order</button>
```

Comment: hello how can i show the arraylist downwards?

Comment: @rinkimeku I'll update my answer

Comment: @rinkimeku I've updated my answer. You can check how to render list now

Answer (score 0):

The script tag is usually just before the closing `</body>` tag.

To reverse an array: `myArray.reverse()`.

To sort an array: `myArray.sort()`.

I wrote a helper function `display(array)` that does the task of displaying the given array into the `#result` div.

I also saved the `#result` div in a constant so we have to compute it only once.

So you get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        //...
    </head>
    <body>
        //...
        <div id="result"></div>
        <button onclick="Org()">Original Order </button>
        <button onclick="Alp()">Alphabetical Order</button>
        <button onclick="Rev()">Reverse Order</button>

        <script>
            const myArray=["Book1","Book2","Book3","Book4"];
            const resultElement = document.getElementById('result');

            function display(array){
                const displayString = array.toString();
                resultElement.innerHTML = displayString;
            }

            function Org(){
                display(myArray);
            }
            function Alp(){
                display(myArray.sort());
            }
            function Rev(){
                display(myArray.reverse());
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thankyou sir it worked but how can i show the array downwards?

Comment: @rinkimeku I'm not sure i understand your question. What are you struggling to achieve?

Comment: hello im sorry but the original has no display value on its own then i pressed the other button it shows different sorting but the original doesn't really change it just stays on what the other button shows

Comment: I tested my code on codepen.io and it seems to work. There is no change between original and alphabetical order right now because the array is originally already in alphabetical order but if you put other words it works

Answer (score 0):

```
function Alp() {   
let temp = [...myArray];   
temp.sort(); 
// code to insert in the view (innerHTML concept);
```

}

```
function Rev() {
let temp = [...myArray];  
temp.sort();
temp.reverse();

// code to insert in the view (innerHTML concept)
```

}

I used **temp** variable because the **sort() and reverse()** methods **modify the arrays in place**